# copy from VBA excel to powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba

I am transferring data from excel to powerpoint slides with an automated script by using EXcel VBA. I'm trying to copy the usedrange of a excel worksheet and paste it to as a image in a powerpoint Template of  4th slide and from there on it should add new slides and copy the remaining worksheets to the next further slides.

The code which i'm currently using is getting the following error "öbject variable or with block variable not set"

Can anyone suggest me the code for the following.

Hope this is clearly explained. If not please ask for more clarification.

Thanks

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim PPpres As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim PPslide As Object
  Dim PpShape As PowerPoint.Shape
  Dim SlideTitle As String
  Dim SlideNum As Integer
  Dim WSrow As Long
  Dim Sh As Shape
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim myshape As Object
'Open PowerPoint and create new presentation
Set PP = GetObject(class, "PowerPoint.Application")
PP.Visible = True
PP.Presentations.Open FileName:=("\\C:\Users\Templates)"
'Specify the chart to copy and copy it
 For Each WS In Worksheets
    If (WS.Name) <> "EOS" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WS.Name).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.CopyPicture
'pSlide.Shapes.Paste
 'Copy Range from Excel
  Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:I8")
'Copy Excel Range
  Rng.Copy
'Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides.Add(5, 33)
 PP.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (4)
Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides(4).Shapes.Paste
'Paste to PowerPoint and position
 PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2 '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
 Set myshape = PPslide.Shapes(PPslide.Shapes.Count)
  'Set position:
      myshape.Left = 66
      myshape.Top = 152
End If
Next
'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate
'Clear The Clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = Falseenter code here`
End Sub
```

Comment: Please correctly format your code by fixing indentations so it is code formatted, and remove the double spaced lines :)

Comment: And say which line errors.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the response.!!.  
Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides(4).Shapes.Paste 
from this line i'm getting the error as " öbject variable or with block variable not set" .  The range of the excel worksheet is copying but it is not pasting in a particular slide (4th slide as mentioned) after opening the template 
of Powerpoint.

Comment: I hadn't spotted that error. You'll need to change `PowerPointApp.` to `PP.` on both lines I believe. Also, on the second from last line in your code, you've merged 2 lines together. The first should be `Application.CutCopyMode = False` and the second should be `'enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
'Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides.Add(5, 33)
PP.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (4)
Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides(4).Shapes.Paste    '<< CHANGING THIS LINE ONLY
'Paste to PowerPoint and position
PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2 '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
```

To:

```
'Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides.Add(5, 33)
PP.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (4)
Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides(4)
'Paste to PowerPoint and position
PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2 '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
```

Also, as per my comment, you'll need to change the following last few lines of your code:

```
'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate
'Clear The Clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = Falseenter code here`
End Sub
```

To:

```
'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
PP.Visible = True
PP.Activate
'Clear The Clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'enter code here
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. working fine.. But getting Run time Error 424 as "Object Required"   in the below line of the code

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
PowerPointApp.Visible = True..

Comment: Apologies for the late reply.. Thank you very much for the quick response.. Helped me a lot

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. If you're completely happy with the answer don't forget to mark it answered.